# Нужно поменять структуру данных в массиве

Tags: javascript

Есть массив

```js
const array = [
  {
    name: 'Teru',
    status: 'In Process',
    is_open: false,
    owner: {
      name: "John Doe",
    },
    listings: {
      _id: "5b1394230c0000428b2385ee",
      ...another_data
    },
  },
  {
     name: 'Farm',
    status: 'Ready',
    is_open: true,
    owner: {
      name: "Alexandra Dario",
    },
    listings: {
      _id: "another_id",
      ...another_data
    },
  },
  {
     name: 'Location',
    status: 'Review',
    is_open: false,
    owner: {
      name: "Ada Doe",
    },
    listings: {
      _id: "5b1394230c0000428b2385ee"(same_id),
      ...another_data
    },
  },
  {
    name: 'Katie_Field',
    status: 'In Process',
    is_open: false,
    owner: {
      name: "John Doe",
    },
    listings: {
      _id: "5b1394230c0000428b2385ee",
      ...another_data
    },
  },
  {
     name: 'Dmitry',
    status: 'In Process',
    is_open: true,
    owner: {
      name: "Jack Wakland",
    },
    listings: {
      _id: "another_id",
      ...another_data
    },
  },
]
```

Нужно помочь с функцией, которая принимает данный массив и возвращает примерно такой массив

```js
const newArray = [
  {
    listings: {
      _id: "5b1394230c0000428b2385ee",
      ...another_data
    },
    
    data: [
      {
        name: 'Teru',
        status: 'In Process',
        is_open: false,
        owner: {
          name: "John Doe",
        },
      },
      {
        name: 'Location',
        status: 'Review',
        is_open: false,
        owner: {
          name: "Ada Doe",
        },
      },
      {
        name: 'Katie_Field',
        status: 'In Process',
        is_open: false,
        owner: {
          name: "John Doe",
        },
      },
    ],
  },

  {
    listings: {
      _id: "another_id",
      ...another_data
    },
    
    data: [
      {
        name: 'Farm',
        status: 'Ready',
        is_open: true,
        owner: {
          name: "Alexandra Dario",
        },
      },
      {
        name: 'Dmitry',
        status: 'In Process',
        is_open: true,
        owner: {
          name: "Jack Wakland",
        },
      },
    ]
  },
]
```

Comment: Не понятно, было куча `listings` в разных объектах массива, а в итоге должен остаться только один из них? Может это опечатка, пропущены квадратные скобки массива?

Comment: Не, просто в объектах это одни и те же `listings`, но по мимо них в этих же объектах есть другие данные, и в data должны попасть эти данные, потому что у них один и тот же `listings`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
    const array = [
      {
        name: 'Teru',
        status: 'In Process',
        is_open: false,
        owner: {
          name: "John Doe",
        },
        listings: {
          _id: "5b1394230c0000428b2385ee",
        },
      },
      {
         name: 'Farm',
        status: 'Ready',
        is_open: true,
        owner: {
          name: "Alexandra Dario",
        },
        listings: {
          _id: "another_id",
        },
      },
      {
         name: 'Location',
        status: 'Review',
        is_open: false,
        owner: {
          name: "Ada Doe",
        },
        listings: {
          _id: "5b1394230c0000428b2385ee",
        },
      },
      {
        name: 'Katie_Field',
        status: 'In Process',
        is_open: false,
        owner: {
          name: "John Doe",
        },
        listings: {
          _id: "5b1394230c0000428b2385ee",
        },
      },
      {
         name: 'Dmitry',
        status: 'In Process',
        is_open: true,
        owner: {
          name: "Jack Wakland",
        },
        listings: {
          _id: "another_id",
        },
      },
    ];
    
    
    const formatArray = array => {
      const result = array.reduce((all, el) => {
        const {listings, ...otherData} = el;
        if(all[listings._id]) {
          all[listings._id].data.push(otherData);
        } else {
          all[listings._id] = {
            listings,
            data: [otherData]
          }
        }
        return all;
      }, {});
    
      return Object.values(result);
    }
    
    console.log(formatArray(array));
```

Я убрал переменную `another_data`, так как у вас она не определена, но вообще можете туда пихать что угодно